# What does $\mbox{diag}(A)$ denote?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, notation

Let $A$ be a $2 \times 2$ matrix. What does $\mbox{diag}(A)$ denote?

It can't refer to a block-diagonal matrix, so does it basically mean $A$ with anything but the diagonal set to $0$?

Comment: Where did you encounter $\mbox{diag}(A)$?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Unfortunately giving the full context is a bit challenging, but the main context would be ML estimation of the cov matrix in FA, e.g. $\hat{\Sigma}=\frac{1}{N} \operatorname{diag}\left[\left\langle x^{\prime} x^{\prime \top}\right\rangle-\left\langle x^{\prime}\langle z\rangle^{\top}\right\rangle \hat{W}^{\top}\right]$. But the source is not very reputable or so so if the usage is not common then the author might have missed redefining the notation.

Comment: Take a look at section 5 of Minka's [Old and new Matrix Algebra useful for Statistics](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/publication/old-new-matrix-algebra-useful-statistics).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\operatorname{diag}(A)$ for a matrix $A$ usually refers to the vector holding the diagonal entries of $A$.

Conversely, $\operatorname{diag}(v)$ for a vector $v$ usually refers to the square matrix which has $v$ on the diagonal and zeros everywhere else.

A third common usage is to let $\operatorname{diag}(A)$ for a matrix $A$ be the matrix with all non-diagonal entries replaced by zero, which is like Misha mentioned in the comments equivalent to $\operatorname{diag}(\operatorname{diag}(A))$ using the other convention.

In your context, given $\hat{\Sigma}=\frac{1}{N} \operatorname{diag}\left[\left\langle x^{\prime} x^{\prime \top}\right\rangle-\left\langle x^{\prime}\langle z\rangle^{\top}\right\rangle \hat{W}^{\top}\right]$ as the estimation of the covariance matrix in a factor analysis, obviously only the 3rd defition applies as the input is a matrix and the output is a matrix.

Comment: This is the Matlab convention. Another existing convention is to write $\operatorname{diag}(A)$ for the vector of diagonal entries, but $\operatorname{Diag}(A)$ or $\operatorname{Diag}(v)$ when the output should be a diagonal matrix (so $\operatorname{Diag}(A)$ is what the Matlab convention would call $\operatorname{diag}(\operatorname{diag}(A))$.

Comment: The convention in Julia is similar to Matlab.  The function `diag(B)` takes a matrix argument and returns a vector result, while the function `Diagonal(b)` takes a vector argument and returns a (diagonal) matrix, but courtesy of Julia's _multiple dispatch_  feature, you can also call this function with a matrix argument and it will behave like `Diagonal(diag(B))` $\,$ It seems odd at first, but I have come to appreciate the **difference** in the function names yet the **consistency** of their return types. $\;$ [NB: calling `diag(b)` throws an error.]